# With EF6, how do I globally set connection properties such as transaction isolation level?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Using Entity Framework 6, how do I set connection properties for every single connection that EF opens?  For example, if I want to override the default Transaction Isolation Level.  Some properties such as Transaction Isolation Level are not configurable using the connection string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried several different approaches that didn't work before finding a solution that worked.  What didn't work was:

Fail #1: In the factory method for my `DbContext` I called `DbContext.Database.ExecuteSql` to set properties on the connection.  This **failed** because EF was resetting the connection before it was used for other calls.

Fail #2: Override `DbContext.SaveChanges` and `DbContext.SaveChangesAsync` to wrap the save in a transaction with the specified isolation level, using either `TransactionScope` or `DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction`.  This worked for saving changes and specifically for isolation level, but didn't help with queries or non-isolation level connection settings.

Fail #3: Added an `IDbTransactionInterceptor` and implementing `IsolationLevelGetting` and `IsolationLevelGot` but these only seem to be able to alter the isolation level getting returned when you query what the transaction isolation level is external to EF code.  EF code does not use this when creating a transaction.

**Success:**

Implement an `IDbConnectionInterceptor`, implementing `Opened`, where I executed commands on the open connection, in this case to set transaction isolation level.  This affected every command executed by EF, confirmed by using SQL Profiler.

Steps:

Create an implementation of `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.IDbConnectionInterceptor`

```
public class ConnectionIsolationLevelInterceptor: IDbConnectionInterceptor
{
    // Have empty implementations for all unused IDbConnectionInterceptor methods
    public void BeganTransaction(DbConnection connection, BeginTransactionInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
    {
    }

    ...
    ... all other unused methods
    ... 

    public void Opened(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
    {
        using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
    }
}
```

In application initialization code, add the interceptor:

```
DbInterception.Add(new ConnectionIsolationLevelInterceptor());
```

SIDE NOTE: There are many different interceptors.  Referencing the [EF 6 source code](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6) is the best way to understand them.  The `DbInterception.Add` static method is a good starting point to find the different types of interceptors.  The Find All References on different dispatcher methods shows where the interceptors are used.